# How to make db table field dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

i am creating plugin in wordpress for contact us form and in that i am creating fields(textbox,textarea etc...) dynamically based on my requirement. so there is no fixed number of fields. i am storing dynamically created fields in my db table.

in some project i may require to create 3 fields and some project i may require to create 5 fields.. my dynamic form is working fine...

now my problem is DB. how do i create table to store contact us data? bcz sometimes there might be 3 fields and sometime there might be more than or less than 3 fields..

so my question is how do i make my table schema for this scenario...

suggestion will be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advnce

Comment: Is the contact us data going to be what you got from the textarea, textbox etc? Also, why do you require 3 in one and 5 in another? Lastly, what would be you max amount of fields, and what would the form look like for that?

Comment: Maybe create a db which tells you how many fields you use and then store the data together with some separator. I mean, in the DB: `textareas`=`'3'`,`dataTextareas`=`'text1|text2|text3'`.It's just an idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**i don't think so it's a good idea to do like this... but i am suggesting you this because in your case it might be useful**

you can do it by `ALTER`...

so what you can do is "When you are creating new field dynamically at that time only you can create new column in your table like this...

```
   ALTER TABLE table_name ADD $name(Column name)  //$name may be your attribute name <input name="">
```

and same way when you are deleting your field at that time you can drop your table column

```
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP $name(Column name) //$name may be your attribute name
```

here i assumed that you have already created table **table_name** (without any fields)

hope it may help you

Comment: I'm not the downvoter,but if you do this, you will create a column for each field.I don't think It's a good idea

Comment: this i can do but my question is is it good way performance wise?

Comment: @Kalpit Not exactly. I think what he wants if the forms has only 1 field store data in the same column. If another form has 2 fields, then create a second column. What you answer, it will create 2 columns even if 2 forms has 1 field

Answer (score 1):

Change table structure is strongly not suggested, it's bad in performance, and may lost data if you drop a column.

So, the original subject 'make db table field dynamic' is possible but not a good plan, we still have alternative plan:

**Store dynamic field in one table column**

Find a way to combine your dynamic field to a string, either use a separator, or use json_encode works, if the column is long enough (TEXT --> MEDIUMTEXT), you can have unlimit dynamic field.

**Create enough column at beginning**

Apearently this not as good as upper plan, but it's easier to understand, and search in these column is easier too.

BTW, Have you considered convert these dynamic column to rows ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the information taken from the form in one table field using an array. That way it should not matter how many question there are.

Should be quite simple take a look at php arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single longtext datatype column in your database table and you just need to serialize your form values and store in the single column.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others. Dynamically creating database tables is bad. The database schema should hardly ever change once a project is complete.

One solution is: 
If you had a contact with multiple addresses, you create a parent/child relationship as follows. Perhaps you can do something similiar with your situation.

Contact
long contactID primary key
name
addressID

Address
long addressID primary key
long contactID foreign key
streetAddress
CityID
CountryID